# Example of non trivial weakly compact set in Banach space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional, non-reflexive Banach space. Then I am looking for an example of a set $A \subseteq X$ which is weakly compact but not strong compact i.e. not norm compact.

Since $A$ is weakly closed it is also norm closed and since $A$ is weakly bounded, it is also bounded. Hence $A$ is necessarily bounded but not totally bounded, as otherwise $A$ were strongly compact.

Furthermore, the unit ball $B_X$ (and of course any translation and rescalings of it) is not an example: If $B_X$ is weakly compact, then the space is reflexive. This is [theorem 3.31](https://books.google.de/books?id=Hcqm4_lW4EkC&lpg=PA75&ots=_YW7BRi8tl&dq=weakly%20compact%20reflexive&pg=PA75&redir_esc=y&hl=de#v=onepage&q=weakly%20compact%20reflexive&f=false).

In $\ell^1$, no such sets exist, as seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227367/weak-vs-norm-compactness-in-ell-1); basically, strong and weak convergence coincide, which is non-trivial. After that it is a consequence of [Eberlein–Šmulian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eberlein%E2%80%93%C5%A0mulian_theorem).

Any partial answers of references are greatly appreciated too. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look at the standard unit vectors, together with the zero vector, in $c_0$.

Comment: Awesome. Let me check

Comment: I think such an example exists for  (and only for ) spaces without the Schur property (weakly convergent sequences are norm convergent).

Comment: @DavidMitra your claim is correct, for if you have a sequence that is weakly convergent but not norm convergent it will have a sub-sequence having distance $>\epsilon$ to the only possible limit, hence that sequence is weakly compact but not norm compact. On the other hand Eberlein Smulian says sequential compactness and compactness are the same for the weak topology, so if something has the Schur property then any weakly compact space is weak sequentially compact, then norm sequentially compact and then norm compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David Mitras answer checks out. Thank you to him.

Consider the set $A:= \{e_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \cup \{0\} \subseteq (c_0, \Vert \cdot \Vert_{\infty})$. Then we have

$A$ is weakly compact. By Eberlein–Šmulian it is enough to show sequential compactness, so let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $A$. Then it will eventually be a subsequence of $(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and hence

$$ \forall y \in (c_0)^* \simeq \ell^{1}: \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} y(x_n) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} y(e_n) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} y_i \delta^i_n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} y_n = 0$$

since $y_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

However, the set is not norm compact since for the sequence $(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ we have $\forall i \neq j: B_{1/2}(e_i) \cap B_{1/2}(e_j) = \emptyset$ and has thus no convergent subsequence.